# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeChild' of null without using removeChild

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't use `removeChild()` and neither I try remove something before's there something.

```
jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeChild' of null
    at m (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at Function.globalEval (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at text script (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at Ut (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at k (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at Object.send (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at Function.ajax (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at Function.w._evalUrl (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at Re (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
```

I receive with `$.ajax` html and I `.html()` it into a div container.

```
$(".kontakt").click(function(a) {
      $('.opt-out').fadeOut();
      a.stopPropagation()
      a.preventDefault()

      $.ajax({async: true,
      type: "POST",
       url: "classes/handle.ajax.class.php",
       data: {
            class: "kontakt"
       },
       success: function(a) {
         $(".link-container").html(a)
         $('.link-container').fadeIn();
         blur();
       }
     })
})
```

Comment: In which line javascript stopped?

Comment: @Mohammad javascript didn't stopped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the source code, I found how ajax is being setup:

```
jQuery.ajaxSetup( {
    accepts: {
        script: "text/javascript, application/javascript, " +
            "application/ecmascript, application/x-ecmascript"
    },
    contents: {
        script: /\b(?:java|ecma)script\b/
    },
    converters: {
        "text script": function( text ) {
            jQuery.globalEval( text ); /* note to this method */
            return text;
        }
    }
} );
```

So, let's look at **globalEval** method:

```
globalEval: function( code ) {
  DOMEval( code );
},
```

And now dive into **DOMEval** method:

```
function DOMEval( code, doc, node ) {
  doc = doc || document;

  var i,
    script = doc.createElement( "script" );

  script.text = code;
  if ( node ) {
    for ( i in preservedScriptAttributes ) {
      if ( node[ i ] ) {
        script[ i ] = node[ i ];
      }
    }
  }
  /* removeChild is being called */
  doc.head.appendChild( script ).parentNode.removeChild( script );
}
```

Where, you may know the `parentNode` is null and calling removeChild on null throws an error. Here, in the preceding code, you can see the `script` has `text` property assigned which value is set as `code`. The `code` is argument of `DOMEval` method. Which actually is the `text` argument as you can find in `ajaxSetup`.

The `ajaxSetup` is being called on `ajax` method (you can look into the source). Which has `url` and `options` arguments. And in the `options` argument you can [find](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings) `dataType` property is used. And if the dataType is not set, it will guess its type in which the server may return a response of `null` or `{}`.

So, I suggest you to set the proper `dataType` while using `jQuery.ajax`. This should fix your issue.

**Update:**

Well, if the response returned by the server is malformed then also it may throw you an error. Thus, verify the server is returning good response. As per your comment, I debugged the code and found response is not returning quite good.

You have the following html in your response as well which is causing the issue:

```
<head>
<meta name='robots' content='noindex'>
</head>
```

Please remove them from the response source, then this should fix the issue.

Comment: I've added it to my ajax call but it didn't changed anything :/ 

`$.ajax({async: true,
   type: "POST",
   url: "classes/handle.ajax.class.php",
   dataType: "text",
   data: {
     class: "kontakt"
   },
   success: function(a) {
     $(".link-container").html(a)
     $('.link-container').fadeIn();
     blur();
   }
 })`

Comment: even If I use as ProcessData = html nothing is changing.
The weird thing is on localhost I don't get this error ...

Comment: Maybe the website link could help. https://photo.core-studio.de/
It happens when you click on "Datenschutz", "Urheberschaft" and "Impressum". Not at "Kontakt"